# Can I run any other display server on Ubuntu Core, except for MIR?

Tags: xorg, qt, ubuntu-core, mir

What are the options to run QT applications on Ubuntu Core ? Should I use docker or are there snapcraft frameworks available for using EGLFS or Xorg ?
The hardware platform that I am using is Intel Atom, and QT works perfectly fine on Ubuntu Desktop 15.04.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on 15.04 Ubuntu Core, there is actually a mir snap in the store, you can install (sudo snappy install mir.mvp-demo)

In addition to that, I posted sometime ago 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/14msTXe_cFulk9z4jFptEjFJzZx58b1mWU_r4VivLkfA
which contains additional steps on how to create a Qt based snap.

Looking forward, I've just recently posted this
https://plus.google.com/+KevinGunnCanonical/posts/fqyGX7rt5Dk

which is for 16.04 and snapcraft2.0 (unfortunately, already out of date with snapcraft2.1, more posts on it's way)

hope this helps